# jQuery onclick ul li i and display children ul if exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a custom mobile menu. The idea is when user clicks on the chevron-right it will **slideToggle the children UL** and add class to the **current LI** (**active**) as well as it will display: block "chevron-down" and display: none "chevron-right". In other words the arrow will be changed from right to down.

```
    jQuery(function(){

  jQuery("#menu-main-menu-m li i.fa-chevron").click(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).closest("li").children("ul").length) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    jQuery(this).children('ul').slideToggle(500);

}
else {

}
  });

});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu-m" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item-has-children menu-item-3 menu-item-ancestor"><a href="#">Open Account</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i><ul class="sub-menu"><li>....</li><li></li></ul>
```

Comment: So what is the issue? You do not know how to show and hide the arrows?

Comment: The jQuery is obviously wrong. It does not do anything right now when I click on the arrow.
And  yes, I need to add the code for the arrows to display and hide.

Comment: `li i.fa-chevron` matches nothing, so no elements will be bound with the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
 $("#menu-main-menu-m i[class*='fa-chevron']").click(function() {
    if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length) {
      $(this).text($(this).text() == "Right" ? "Down" : "Right");
      $(this).closest("li").children("ul").toggleClass('active');
      $(this).closest("li").children("ul").slideToggle(500);
   }
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzseLj27/2/

Comment: Almost. The active class is not added. Also I need to hide the chevron-right and display chevron-down.

Comment: In the example, i used text. But you can use image and use classname instead of text.

Comment: Thank you but I am struggling to change the chevron-right to chevron-bottom class. I did this:
jQuery(this).removeClass( "fa-chevron-right" ).addClass( "fa-chevron-down" );

BUT, when the menu is closed the DOWN arrow stays. I need the Right arrow. In other words is there a way to toggle between an existing class  (fa-chevron-right) TO (fa-chevron-down) and vice versa. Toggle.class does not work because it ADDS and removes the new ADDED class. I need a completely new class and removed the OLD.

Comment: Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/rzseLj27/4/ . It has changes for css image toggling.

Comment: Thank you! Btw, I wanted the LI to be active, so .children("ul") should be deleted in that line.
Again, thank you :)

Comment: Excellent Implementation. Still Works as expected in 2022. Thanks in advance @DinoMyte

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea using CSS and binding the click event to the elements.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#menu-main-menu-m").on("click", "li i.fa", function() {  
     console.log("here");
      var li = $(this).closest("li");
      li.toggleClass("active");
      li.find(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
  });

});
```

```css
.menu li i {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu li.active i {
  display: none;  
}

.menu li i + i {
  display: none;  
}
.menu li.active i + i {
  display: inline-block;  
}

.sub-menu { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul id="menu-main-menu-m" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item-has-children menu-item-3 menu-item-ancestor"><a href="#">Open Account</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>....</li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works as well. I just need to display the down chevron and hide the current (right chevron).
2 ways - 
1. change the class from fa-chevron-right to fa-chevron-bottom
2. display: none to chevron-right and display: block to chevron-bottom